# Change space on both displays?

Tags: macos, display, spaces

I'm trying to work out how to get the best out of the new multi-display support in OS X Mavericks. I'm very used to my workflow when I was changing space on both displays with single gesture on my trackpad - I'm a programmer so I had text editors in one pair of spaces and engine editor in another pair - now I have to do much more to get the same result. I know that you can disable separate spaces for different displays, but that (for a reason I can't think of) disables dock and menu bar on my second display.

I'd like to have either one of

1. Same spaces with menu bar and dock on both displays.
2. Separate spaces that can be changed simultaneously.

Can this be achieved? Using some third party software perhaps? I'm also not afraid of doing terminal magic or writing an applescript.

Thanks!